# How to compile startuptime for ver 8?

Tags: compile-vim

When I try using `vim --startuptime myfile`, it reports it is not compiled in.
There seems to be no instructions on how to compile in startuptime. I have tried adding `--enable-startuptime` to the configure, but that only complains. Looking through the Makefile finds no startuptime. :help offers no help. Googling for several hours offers no help.

How does one get this feature "compiled"?

Answer (score 1):

It's all in [:h :version](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%3Aversion) and [:h +feature-list](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%2Bfeature-list)

```
...
The first column shows the smallest version in which
they are included:
   T    tiny (always)
   S    small
   N    normal
   B    big
   H    huge
   m    manually enabled or depends on other features
 (none) system dependent
...
...
N  *+startuptime*   |--startuptime| argument
```

It requires version no less than `normal` to include `+startuptime`, most people use `huge` to include as many features as possible:

```
./configure --with-features=huge
```